# Head Function in R vs opening dataset manually

Tags: r

When doing a first glimpse at the data set, what are the advantages and disadvantages of using the head function as opposed to manually clicking and opening the data set in R environment?

Comment: What do yo mean by "manually clicking and opening the data set in R environment"?

Comment: I am assuming you're talking about the `View` method in Rstudio, which gets called when you click on the dataset from the environment pane?

Comment: @smacdonald I Guess I am referring to clicking the data set in the data section under the environment tab. Sorry if I said it wrongly, just started out with R and does not know the stuff well.

Comment: @ar7 Yep, it's the view method in Rstudio.

Comment: This question seems a bit vague. Pros/Cons? I suspect they are entirely subjective. Do you prefer keyboard to mouse? `head`. Do you want to see how much the columns vary over more of the data? `View`. Do you want to view the data in a side window without having it scroll off-screen as you do more things? `View`. ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since View is more visual and loads all the rows in the data frame, it requires more memory to load the data. `head` is more raw and accesses only the number of rows you specify there. So head is more efficient in terms of memory, but it will not be as intutive as View when the data has too many columns.

It is a tradeoff between efficiency and visual appeal.

Edit: Corrected that View is Rstudio specific. It is not.

Comment: My bad. Corrected it now. Thanks for pointing it out.